# HttpURL Connection setReadTimeout

Tags: httpurlconnection

> public void setReadTimeout (int timeoutMillis)
>
> Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up. ***Reading will fail with a SocketTimeoutException if the timeout elapses before data becomes available***. The default value of 0 disables read timeouts; read attempts will block indefinitely.
>
> Parameters
> timeoutMillis - the read timeout in milliseconds. Non-negative.

What is the meaning of info with bold characters?Is it good to include this in network connection?

Comment: Which java class are you referring to ? HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

Answer (score 0):

It indicates the time between when the socket is connected and when it expects response for the request the client makes.

Default value is good enough unless you want to return the call within a certain duration and you are sure the server doesn't exceed responses beyond certain time.